# excel grouping and subtotals

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a excel with the following fields:

```
Date        Name    Task
========================
16/09/2015  AT      1

16/09/2015  AT      2

16/09/2015  AT      3

16/09/2015  BT      4

16/09/2015  BT      5

16/09/2015  CT      6

15/09/2015  AT      7

15/09/2015  BT      8

15/09/2015  CT      9
```

The excel sheet basically contains the every date tasks assigned to each person.

What I want is, I want to total of how many task was assigned to each person daily. Something like this:

```
Date            Name     Daily Task Total
=========================================
16/09/2015      A               3

16/09/2015      B               2

16/09/2015      C               1

15/09/2015      A               1

15/09/2015      B               1

15/09/2015      C               1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using Pivot in excel.

Steps:
1. select your data.
2. Goto Insert tab and click on Pivot
3. Select Date,Name and Task Field List [Field list opens up at right side]
4. Put Date couln in Rows Label
5. Put Name in Column Labels
6. Count of Tasks in Values

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I was about to post saying that I googled around and worked it out with Pivot Tables... Thank you. It worked out.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Pivot table having as row the date and name, and as value the count of Task.

Answer (score 0):

Use countifs function to solve this.

[image]

`=COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$19,"="&F3,$B$3:$B$19,"="&G3)`

Will look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take all of your data from on columns A and B and paste it to another sheet.
Then select the 2 columns on the new sheet and choose the ribbon data -> remove duplicates.
On the same new sheet on c2 enter the formula (assuming your first sheet named Sheet1):

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!B:B,B2)
```